# How to make monthly subscription payment by paypal in php?

Tags: laravel-4, paypal

I am building a web app in laravel 4.

I tried to make a monthly subscription payment via paypal.

I had added a subscribe button in my billing page.

I have tested the link. It could redirect to paypal site and ask approve.

But how does the server know the user has successfully paid?

Answer (score 1):

After successfull payment paypal sends a IPN to the address u provide...By this notification your server can come to know about the payment.login to paypal account>>setting>>ipn link or url>>and set it to a php file which can recieve ipn variables and detect about the payment